# Is there any method in`SVNKit` which distinguishes the first revision where a file was checked in?

Tags: svn, svnkit

My project has a function that a user can select a specific file on a selected revision in `repo A`, and my program will copy it to `repo B`.

I use the method `getRevision` in `SVNDirEntry`, to get the revision of the specific file.  But it always returns the latest revision, which might lead the user to select a revision that isn't relevant to that file (because I use that revision to generate the `<option>` on web page).

Example:
the file `InfoStruc.java` is checked into `repo A` on revision 61 the first time, and on revision 946 the second time.

The method, `getRevision`in`SVNDirEntry`, would return 946.
If user selects `InfoStruc.java` on revision (1~60), it would lead to the file not found error.

Is there any method in `SVNKit` that could distinguish which revision is the first revision where some file was checked in ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time an item is committed, it will be shown as an Add action. You'll have to look through all log entries for that item until you come to the one where it's an Add instead of a Change.